# Unity, dependency error importing google play game services

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I update google the google play games services as described here: [unity plugin](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity) , but i have the following error:

> Google.JarResolver.ResolutionException: Cannot find candidate artifact for com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.4+
>     at Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport.DependOn (System.String group, System.String artifact, System.String version) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at GooglePlayGames.Editor.GPGSDependencies..cctor () [0x00024] in /Users/gabriele/Documents/number777pro/number/Number777/Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/GPGSDependencies.cs:46 
>   UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:SetLoadedEditorAssemblies(Assembly[])

i try to find a solution, but without success, anyone know how to solve ?

Comment: You need to update the Google Repository and Android Support Repository components via Android SDK Manager.

Comment: i did it, i also try to redownload the android sdk but it didn't resolve the error

Comment: hi @GabrielePicco , really you should TICK the answer below!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was solved by updating the following inside android sdk manager:
1. android support repository
2. Google Play services
3. Google Repository

---

FYI **on a Mac...**

Go to your Android tools directory which is likely here ..

> cd /Users/ ... /Library/Android/android-sdk-macosx/tools

and run this

> ./android update sdk --no-ui

it will install a very large number of downloads (30 mins), including it looks like everything you need to resolve this problem.

```
 ...
  Downloading Local Maven repository for Support Libraries, revision 28
  Installing Local Maven repository for Support Libraries, revision 28
    Installed Local Maven repository for Support Libraries, revision 2899%)
  Downloading Google Play services, revision 29
  Installing Google Play services, revision 29
    Installed Google Play services, revision 2996%)
  Downloading Google Repository, revision 25
  Installing Google Repository, revision 25
    Installed Google Repository, revision 2599%)
 ...
  Done. 34 packages installed.
```

If you're a Unity-Mac user, it's likely you have not installed Android Studio, but rather only the various SDKs.  In this way you can easily update, without bothering with Studio as such.  Conversely if you just run

> ./android

it will open the ever-handy AndroidSDKManager (ie, an actual gui app running on your Mac). You can then do it that way, if you know exactly what to install to get Play Services working, perhaps saving some downloads.  Note that fortunately SDKManager can run on its own this way (**no frickin' java on your Mac**) without launching Studio.

Hope it helps someone.